# Как правильно перенаправить вывод работы потоков в TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть два работающих потока(они должны отработать определенное количество раз), которые периодически выводят некую информацию, к примеру - `System.out.println("I am Thread-0")`. Если я сразу вывожу это в TextArea, то при вводе числа, больше 8 (это сколько раз они должны отработать), программа заканчивает работу с ошибками. Так как лучше отправлять информацию в TextArea?

Такс, собственно вот у меня класс, где создаются потоки:

```
package sample.lab3;


import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Task3 {

public static class Parcel {
    public int num_of_parcels;
    private int counter_of_parcels = 0;
    private int parcel = 0;
    TextArea ta;

    public  Parcel(TextArea tArea) {
        this.ta = tArea;
    }

    public synchronized void get() {
        while (parcel < 1) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException err) {
                System.out.println("Some error has occured with getting a parcel\n");
            }
        }

        parcel--;
        ta.appendText("Name of the thread is Thread-1\n" + "Number of the parcel is " + counter_of_parcels + "\n");
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void send() {
        while (parcel > 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException err) {
                System.out.println("Some error has occured with sending a parcel" + "\n");
            }
        }
        parcel++;
        counter_of_parcels++;
        ta.appendText("Name of the thread is Thread-0\n" + "Number of the parcel is " + counter_of_parcels + "\n");
        notify();
    }
}

public static class Receiver extends Thread {
    Parcel parcel;

    Receiver(Parcel parcel) {
        this.parcel = parcel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < parcel.num_of_parcels; i++) {
            parcel.get();
        }
    }
}
public static class Sender extends Thread {
    Parcel parcel;

    Sender(Parcel parcel) {
        this.parcel = parcel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < parcel.num_of_parcels; i++) {
            parcel.send();
        }
    }
}

public void doTask3(String[] args, TextArea tArea) {
    if (args[0].length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("You are allowed to write only one parameter!");
        return;
    }

    try {
        Parcel parcel = new Parcel(tArea);
        Sender sender = new Sender(parcel);
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver(parcel);

        parcel.num_of_parcels = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        sender.start();
        receiver.start();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("Your parameter isn't correct!");
    }
}
}
```

И Controller, где вызывается doTask3() и передается TextArea(resultOfParcels):

```
addInfo3.setOnAction(e -> {
    args[0] = numberOfParcels.getText();
    Task3 t3 = new Task3();
    t3.doTask3(args, resultOfParcels);
});
```

На начальных порах выводит все отлично, если args[0] равен до 15 где-то. А после появляются ошибки. Вот собственно и они:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:756)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:140)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:210)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:771)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1022)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:222)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:430)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Text.doComputeGeomBounds(Text.java:1173)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Text.access$300(Text.java:127)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Text$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Text.java:148)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.TextHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(TextHelper.java:90)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.computeGeomBounds(NodeHelper.java:115)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3837)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3799)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3747)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$3.computeBounds(Node.java:6837)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9764)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9734)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3427)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView.layoutChildren(TextAreaSkin.java:1311)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1204)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2482)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:519)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:499)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:492)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:320)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите код, как минимум где ошибка. В данный момент, можно лишь догадаться, что у вас ошибка IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Код добавил в сам вопрос

Comment: Помимо прочих ошибок, которые точно есть в коде, самая главная - попытка   работать с компонентами графического интерфейса из потоков. JavaFX не является потокобезопасной!

Comment: @Ksen ,подскажите, пожалуйста, у вас в внутри  `class Task3`  еще несколько статичных классов?

Comment: только те 3, которые уже показаны выше